# Servlet dispatcher is currently unavailable

Tags: java, spring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/spring"/>
        <property name="username" value="monty"/>
        <property name="password" value="indian"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>uk.co.vinoth.spring.domain.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myUserDAO" class="uk.co.vinoth.spring.dao.UserDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="/user/*.htm" class="uk.co.vinoth.spring.web.UserController" >
        <property name="userDAO" ref="myUserDAO" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The above is my bean configuration, why do i get error when i run my application. My logs folder is empty...

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@122c9df
 org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1436)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:966)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3996)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Dec 22, 2010 3:44:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /interMedix threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1436)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:966)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3996)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Dec 22, 2010 3:44:48 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8181
Dec 22, 2010 3:44:48 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Dec 22, 2010 3:44:48 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/27  config=null
Dec 22, 2010 3:44:48 PM org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreLoader load
INFO: Find registry server-registry.xml at classpath resource
Dec 22, 2010 3:44:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 558 ms
Dec 22, 2010 3:44:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
INFO: Servlet dispatcher is currently unavailable
Dec 22, 2010 3:50:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
INFO: Servlet dispatcher is currently unavailable
```

But i have added spring-web-mvc to my class path which does contain this class file.

Comment: please post the code causing the problem, so that we can look and find errors if any

Comment: Please check server logs, in your $TOMCAT_HOME/logs directory. Typically you can see something happening in catalina.out, localhost-*.out . Did you add the tomcat-connector jar to your project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But i have added spring-web-mvc to my
>   class path which does contain this
>   class file.

How did you add something to your CLASSPATH?

If you're creating a web app, the only appropriate thing is to put .class files under WEB-INF/classes and .jar files under WEB-INF/lib.  If you did anything else, I'd say that it's wrong.  Modifications of the startup script should not be done; local environment variables will be ignored and unlikely to be set on the server you deploy to.

UPDATE:

If you tell me that you've done everything right according to your IDE, I'd recommend one last check: Look at the zipped or exploded WAR file that you actually deploy to Tomcat and make sure that you can see the JAR with the .class file that the error mentions.  If it's not part of the WAR, you have to figure out what went wrong with your packaging.  If you think the JAR is there, open it and find the .class and check the path.

You have to believe the error message you see.  Instead of saying "I'm doing everything right", it's better to say "What have I missed?"

Comment: I am adding it via right clicking the project and adding the external libraries.

Answer (score 3):

A `ClassNotFoundException` suggests that you *don't* have Spring on the classpath. Make sure it's in your WAR's `lib` directory.

Also, make sure you also have `commons-logging.jar` in your classpath. Spring depends on this.