# HTTP Status 404 - Servlet dispatcher is not available

Tags: java, spring

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>WicketSpringHibernate</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>WicketSpringHibernate</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>JBoss repository</id>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    </dependency> 

<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>taglibs</groupId>
<artifactId>standard</artifactId>
<version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
         <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>geronimo-spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-spec-jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

     <!-- MySQL database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate framework -->
        <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>javassist</groupId>
       <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
       <version>3.8.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate annotation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate-annotations</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate-commons-annotations</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->


  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The above is my POM.xml. My Apache logs says...

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1438)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:966)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3996)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:740)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1271)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1570)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1579)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Dec 22, 2010 8:26:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
INFO: Servlet dispatcher is currently unavailable
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508058/servlet-dispatcher-is-currently-unavailable is this the same one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in this line:

> `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`

Basically your web app is missing JAR files for Spring Core and/or Spring MVC.  They should be in the webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` directory, along with other JAR files that your webapp depends on.  Take a look at what is there, and try to figure out why `DispatcherServlet` is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IDE and trying to run it from within the ide, you will need to explicilitly tell ide to export maven dependencies into web-inf/lib

if you are using eclipse;
Project Properties
Deployment Assembly
Add -> Maven dependencies and tell eclipse to export those into web-inf/lib

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with using Maven for a spring app, but just at a glance it looks like you're pulling down the testing architecture rather than the actual spring binaries.  This is also consistent with the error you're getting: it can't find the DispatcherServlet class.  I'd double check to make sure you have the correct spring dependency listed in your POM.xml